# How do I get a default value from first in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

`(> 1 (first []))` returns NullPointerException.

How can I make `(first [])` return a default value, such as 0, instead of nil?

Comment: Should it return default value if the first returns only `nil`? What if the first value of the seq is `false` (`[false]`) or `nil` (`[nil]`)?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl Oh, geez... just if the list is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `or` to bypass the `nil` value

```
(> 1 (or (first []) 0))
```

Because in Clojure, `nil` is treated as a falsy value.

Comment: Thanks for the revision, I almost choked at the first one ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `or` solution is good for this case. For cases where `or` is not sufficient, another option is to use the `with-exception-default` macro [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#default-value-in-case-of-exception):

```
(with-exception-default default-val & body)
 "Evaluates body & returns its result.  In the event of an exception the
  specified default value is returned instead of the exception."

(with-exception-default 0
  (Long/parseLong "12xy3"))
;=> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`fnil`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fnil):

A function that replaces a `nil` second argument to `>` with 0 is ...

```
(fnil > nil 0)
```

So that, for instance,

```
((fnil > nil 0) 1 (first []))
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

imho you should clearly define the functional objects in your design

since you need a functionality: given a collection coll extract the first element or default to 0 then you should have a separate function for that.

e.g.

```clojure
(defn first-or-zero [coll] 
 (if (seq coll)
   (first coll) 0))
```

Although a bit cumbersome to write (and the `or` macro does seem to get you there quicker you are missing out on the powerful concept that is FP.

a) doing this way you have a pure functional description of what you need to do
b) you can test it either by proof or by unit-testing
c) you can reuse it all over the place with minimum impact on change

A more FP way of doing it would be:

```clojure
(defn first-or-default 
  ([coll] (first-or-default coll 0))
  ([coll dflt-val] 
   (if (seq coll)
      (first coll) dflt-val)))
```

Then just call: `(< 1 (first-or-default coll 0))`

Comment: I personally don't see how using a `or` macro makes the code less functional. And I would personally prefer to reuse `or` since it is part of clojure, rather than introducing a separate function.

Comment: This is the best solution because it handles collections whose first element is `nil`, but I can't really upvote it because of the absurd bluster about `or` not being functional.

Comment: I didn't say `or` is not functional - being a macro it will replace to whatever (that whatever is functional).
I just said that for the stated issue there is a 'more' functional way of doing things. 
My intention was that for a newcomer on Clojure/Lisp to also provide some insight into the logic of or :)